# Django default tables

Tags: python, database, django

When working with databases with Django, it automatically creates 12 default tables in the database.

[image]

I understand that I need `dango_session` for storing the session and probably `django_site`. But why do I need the others?

In PHP I used to store users in my own custom tables. Shouldn't I do that anymore?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The tables are created because you have `django.contrib.auth`, `django.contrib.sessions`, and so on in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. You shouldn't delete the tables if the apps are installed, as Django will expect them to exist.

None of the contrib apps are required to run Django. However, I highly recommend that you use the Django `auth` and `sessions` app instead of writing your own. For example, if you use the auth app, you don't need to worry about how to hash passwords, and there are lots of helpful views included to log users in, reset passwords and so on.

Comment: What if I want to add more fields to the `auth_user`, should I create a new table for it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model